# Confidence intervals for bootstrapped multinomial proportions: Sison-Glaz?

Tags: bootstrap, multinomial-distribution, statsmodels

I read the rules and looked for similar posts, but couldn't find any. New to the platform, so if I missed anything, pardon me.

I have started looking into uncertainty quantification and I want to express the uncertainty in the proportions of a multinomial distribution.

There are 6 different categories and 8 observations (I am aware this is extremely limited). These have been parametrically bootstrapped through Numpy's [Multinomial distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multinomial.html) and I collected the proportions for every category for every simulated sample. Next, I want to compile the 95% confidence intervals for these collected proportions for every category.

I figured I would use Sison-Glaz's approach as described in *Simultaneous Confidence Intervals and Sample Size Determination for Multinomial Proportions* and available at Python's Statsmodels [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.multinomial_proportions_confint.html).

After checking the Statsmodels documentation, I am familiar with how to conduct the Statsmodel function to the original data, but I do not grasp how this can be applied to bootstrapped values. Assuming it is intended to apply to bootstrapped data.

Any help is welcome: insight into Sison-Glaz's approach, another CI method for bootstrapped multinomial proportions, different packages. Again, I just started to explore the field and any direction, general or specific, is very much appreciated.